# Current Electricity

Tags: waves, electromagnetic-radiation, acceleration, electric-current, calculus

If 
$$
\frac{dQ}{dt} = I
$$
and if an accelerated current produces E.M. waves (radiation), does that mean $d^2Q/dt^2$ (second derivative of a charge w.r.t. time) will give me the magnitude of the wave produced?

Comment: Hi Jay ! Can you perhaps explain to us the meaning of "magnitude of wave" ? The present form of the question renders it unclear about what you're exactly asking, and will likely be put *on-hold* as per the [site guidelines](http://physics.stackexchange.com/help) until it is edited to be made clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is true that accelerating charges radiate energy in the form of electromagnetic radiation. However, the relationship is not a naive ratio between the acceleration and the amplitude of the electromagnetic wave. Rather, you need to invoke Maxwell's equations.

Specifically, there is Ampere's law:

$$\nabla\times{\bf B}={\bf J}+\frac{\partial{\bf E}}{\partial t},$$

which tells you that if the current ${\bf J}$ is varying with time, there will be a magnetic field ${\bf B}$ that will also vary with time. And then there is Faraday's law:

$$\nabla\times{\bf E}=-\frac{\partial{\bf B}}{\partial t},$$

which tells you that a time-varying magnetic field induces an electric field ${\bf E}$, which, in turn, will contribute further to the magnetic field as per Ampere's law.

From these equations it should be evident that although the magnitude of $\partial{\bf J}/\partial t$ contributes to the magnitude of the emitted radiation indirectly (there will be a time-varying component in ${\bf B}$ that is proportional to $\partial{\bf J}/\partial t$ and this, in turn, contributes to ${\bf E}$) the relationship is by no means obviously linear.